# Group related objects in Django

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm building an app where you can search for objects in a database (let's assume the objects you search for are persons). What I want to do is to group related objects, for example married couples. In other words, if two people share the same last name, we assume that they are married (not a great example, but you get the idea). The last name is the only thing that identifies two people as married. 
In the search results I want to display the married couples next to each other, and all the other persons by themselves.

Let's say you search for "John", this is what I want:

```
John Smith - Jane Smith
John Adams - Nancy Adams
John Washington
John Andersson
John Ryan
```

Each name is then a link to that person's profile page.

What I have right now is a function that finds all pairs, and returns a list of tuples, where each tuple is a pair. The problem is that on the search results, every name that is in a pair is listed twice.
I do a query for the search query (Person.objects.filter(name__contains="John")), and the result of that query is sent to the match function. I then send both the original queryset and the match function result to the template.
I guess I could just exclude every person that the match function finds a match for, but I don't know, but is that the most efficient solution?

Edit:

As I wrote in a comment, the actual strings that I want to match are not identical. To quote myself:

> In fact, the strings I want to match are not identical, instead they
>   look more like this: "foo2(bar13)" - "foo2(bar14)". That is, if two
>   strings have the same foo id (2), and if the bar id is an odd number
>   (13), then its match is the bar id + 1 (14). I have a regular
>   expression to find these matches

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First get your objects sorted by last name:

```
def keyfun(p):
    return p.name.split()[-1]

persons = sorted(Person.objects.all(), key = keyfun)
```

Then use groupby:

```
from itertools import groupby
for lname, persons in groupby(persons, keyfun):
    print ' - '.join(p.name for p in persons)
```

**Update** Yes, this solution works for your new requirement too. All you need is a stable way to generate keys for each item, and replace the body of the keyfun with it:

```
from re import findall
def keyfun(p):
    v1, v2 = findall(p.name, '\d+')
    tot = int(v1) + int(v2) % 2
    return tot
```

Your description for how to generate the key for each item is not clear enough, although you should be able to figure it out yourself with the above example.

Comment: Nice solution! The problem is that it's not a simple as "last names" (I should have made this clearer in the OP). In fact, the strings I want to match are not identical, instead they look more like this: "foo2(bar13)" - "foo2(bar14)". That is, if two strings have the same foo id (2), and if the bar id is an odd number (13), then its match is the bar id + 1 (14). I have a regular expression to find these matches, so is it possible to extend your solution to fit my case? I'm not 100% sure I understand how groupby works.